# Yandex API пропадает метка при перемещении

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Добрый день. 
Есть такой пример на сайте яндекса.
http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/deliveryCalculator
В нем, если взять метку А перетащить и отпустить, то она пропадает. Почему это происходит? И как сделать так, что бы она не пропадала?

Comment: А как сделать так, что бы она не стиралась, а при перемещении тоже считала маршрут?

Answer (score 1):

Ну так и правильно что пропадает.

Там ведь стоит расчет маршрута по клику. Когда происходит клик ставится точка и высчитываются данные. про перемещение точки ничего нет, оно просто стирает точку А и все.